# why does adding headers to an angular request cause it to not work right at all

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm currently trying to add headers to an angular HTTP request, but I don't understand why as soon as I try to add headers, neither the header is set, or the payload sent...

```
const accessToken = this.discordService.getAccessToken()
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': accessToken
  })
};
console.log('access token', accessToken)
this.http.post(environment.functionsUrl + '/setup', JSON.stringify(
    { userId: userId })).subscribe(r => console.log(r));
```

This results in the payload being passed, but the "Authorization" header isn't set:

[image]

However, when I add the headers in:

```
const accessToken = this.discordService.getAccessToken()
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': accessToken
  })
};
console.log('access token', accessToken)
this.http.post(environment.functionsUrl + '/setup', JSON.stringify(
    { userId: userId }), httpOptions).subscribe(r => console.log(r));
```

There is no "payload" section and the header still isn't set:

[image]

Angular versions:

```
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
```

Comment: Is the value of `accessToken` formatted properly? Like, does it have the word *bearer*  at the beginning, or what ever is appropriate?

Comment: @R.Richards It does